# How to work around Haskell's Int shift argument in a fold using xor?

Tags: haskell, bit-shift, fold, rijndael, bitwise-xor

I have some code (generating the Rijndael S-box, for fun) that looks like this:

```
q0 = q  ⊕  shiftL q  1
q1 = q0 ⊕  shiftL q0 2
q2 = q1 ⊕  shiftL q1 4
```

It seems kind of silly - wouldn't it be the perfect situation for a fold? But I can't use a fold because `shiftL` requires an `Int` for the distance to shift, and of course `xor` requires `Bits`.

It seems awkward to me that a function meant to operate on `Bits` won't accept `Bits` for all its arguments. I'd be curious to hear the rational for that, but I'm more eager to know if there's any elegant way to achieve the fold I want.

Comment: What is the result you are looking for? Only `q2`, or all `qi`s?

Comment: I only require q2.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand what the problem is from the code you posted. Are you trying to use something other than `1`, `2`, `4` as the shift amount? Because what you wrote can be translated as a simple left fold, no? ``sbox q = foldl' (\ q' i -> q' `xor` shiftL q' i) q [1, 2, 4]``

Comment: Thank you, that works. But what I really wanted was the simple:
`foldl' (xor . shiftL) q`, which would work if it weren't for the `Int` that `shiftL` demands.

Comment: The `Bits` typeclass represents bitvectors with bitwise operations. Instances of `Bits` are not necessarily meant to be interpreted as integers. On the other hand, `Int` is very common as a type of indices of a vector. Hence, `shiftL` accepts an `Int`.

Comment: `xor . shiftL = \q -> xor (shiftL q)` wouldn't type check.

Comment: Thank you everyone, I guess I was just looking for a way to force the `Int` to accept `Bits`, since, though they're not always meant to represent integers, they certainly always can. But I'll live with it; I like what Jon Purdy wrote.

Comment: @sacheie: The problem with `xor . shiftL` isn’t the mismatch between `Bits a => a` and `Int`, but rather the fact that it’s not implicitly lifted over multiple arguments; to get the behaviour of `\ q -> xor q . shiftL q` point-free, you could use the `(a ->)` applicative to write `liftA2 (.) xor shiftL`, or arrows to write `xor &&& shiftL >>> uncurry (.)`, but neither is very readable.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jon - the version with liftA2 was exactly what I was looking for. I guess readability is a matter of taste; I'm not a big fan of lambda expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jon Purdy inferred what I should have stated clearly - I wanted a point-free function to pass to fold, and he provided one: `liftA2 (.) xor shiftL`.

Answer (score 3):

`foldl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b` iteratively applies a function starting with a `b` to a list of `a`s until the list is exhausted and then returns the result. In this case our `a`s can be the *shift lengths*. So `1`, `2`, `4`. We can construct such a list with `iterate :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]`. Indeed:

```
powers2 = iterate (2*) 1
```

Now we can feed that list to `foldl`. The function `foldl` performs is `\qi s -> xor qi (shiftL qi s)`. So the complete function would be:

```
qn :: (Num a, Foldable t, Bits [a]) => Int -> r -> t Int -> [a]
qn n q = foldl (\qi s -> xor qi (shiftL qi s)) q $ take n $ iterate (2*) 1
```

So if we call `qn 3 q` we perform the function three times on `q` and thus obtain the `q2` in your example. For example:

```
Prelude Data.Bits> qn 3 15
1285
```

Since:

```
q           = 0000 0000 1111
shiftL q  1 = 0000 0001 1110
              --------------
q0          = 0000 0001 0001
shiftL q0 2 = 0000 0100 0100
              --------------
q1          = 0000 0101 0101
shiftL q1 4 = 0101 0101 0000
              --------------
q2          = 0101 0000 0101
```

which is the binary equivalent of 1285.